# Visual studio 2019 community does not show Authentication with azure active directory connected services?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

Visual studio 2019 community does not show Authentication with azure active directory connected services?

I have update dot net framework version but it will not showing me azure AD connected service.

Comment: Did you select Microsoft Identity Platform as Authentication type while creating your dot net app? in VS studio?

Comment: Refer here https://i.imgur.com/NQ3Y9bL.png Is this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked in my environment( VS 2019) and I was also unable to see the option for Authentication with azure active directory connected services.

*I have installed .Net 5.0(out of support) and .Net 3.1(out of support) in VS 2019.*

Go to VS installer> Modify> Individual Components> select .Net 5.0(out of support) and .Net 3.1(out of support).

[image]

I could see the option **connected services** in both *.Net 5.0 and .Net 3.1.*
[image]

After selecting Microsoft Identity platform, signin with your account and you can see the all the available tenants, click on Finish.

[image]

As it can be seen below, I could configure Connected Services.

[image]

If you are still facing the issue, you can try selecting ***Microsoft Identity platform*** as Authentication Type while creating Application.
[image]

**Note:** Visual Studio 2019 doesn't support .Net 6.0 version.